# cmd dos compare strings with while loop

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd

We need to check the status of a scheduled task to decide what other tasks to run after that, e.g.:

```
c:\software\scripts>find /I /C "Running" status.txt

---------- STATUS.TXT: 0
```

We'd like to know how to write the cmd script to perform a "while" loop on this command until the output becomes

```
---------- STATUS.TXT: 1
```

We thought about using `set /p teststring=find /I /C "Running" status.txt` , hoping that the output from that command would set parameter teststring to "---------- STATUS.TXT: 0" and then compare with "---------- STATUS.TXT: 1", but we aren't sure.

How do we script to accomplish our end goal?

Answer (score 2):

Batch syntax doesn't provide a `while` instruction, so you'll have to work with `goto`. Also there's no need to compare strings or count the occurrences of the search string. `find` returns a different `%errorlevel%` depending on whether the search string was found or not. Try this:

```
:LOOP
find /i "running" status.txt >nul
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto LOOP
```

It might be a good idea to add some delay before trying again, too:

```
:LOOP
find /i "running" status.txt >nul
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
  ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
  goto LOOP
)
```

**Edit:** As suggested by @dbenham, a more compact form could look like this:

```
:LOOP
find /i "running" status.txt >nul || ( ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul & goto LOOP )
```

Comment: +1, though I prefer the following more compact syntax: `find /i "running" status.txt >nul || goto LOOP`. I agree, adding parentheses and a PING delay is advised.